# iOS 7 location service turn off issue

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am developing an application where I enabled background service for location updates.
But in iOS 7 when I ***"turn off Location service"*** from Settings, from that point my app is not running any more. Any one have any idea about this?  How to run my app in background if location service is turn off in iOS 7. In iOS 6 it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesnt quite make sense.  When you say 'when I "turn off Location service" from Settings, from that point my app is not running any more' do you mean the whole app isnt running, or that background services are not running?

Ive found there are two things you need to do to ensure your app will get GPS location updates while in the background for iOS7.  Check that location services are generally enabled in settings : [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled], and that App Background Refresh is enabled : ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable) .  That is once you have enabled background location updates by setting this option in the apps' info.plist file.

Comment: If your location service is disable from setting, there is no way to run app in background, Except background Task. No matter backgorund refresh is ON. I checked and tested so many time then only I posted this question.